# Android Studio Error - Fragment - Navigation drawer

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

When I Run the app I get the following error:

```
10-20 14:47:22.829 29044-29044/com.example.ivanp.meteostanica E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: com.example.ivanp.meteostanica, PID: 29044
                                                                            java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.configureTransitions(BackStackRecord.java:1153)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.beginTransition(BackStackRecord.java:1060)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:662)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

I'm new to Android Studio and I was just following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H4R-hz56oBA

This is the MainActivity.java :

```
package com.example.ivanp.meteostanica;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_tvrdjava) {
            TvrdjavaFragment tvrdjavaFragment = new TvrdjavaFragment(); //Create object from Fragment
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.relativeLayoutFragment,
                    tvrdjavaFragment,
                    tvrdjavaFragment.getTag()).commit();


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_bubanj) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_celekula) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_cegar) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_podesavanja) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_onama) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is the TvrdjavaFragment.java :

```
package com.example.ivanp.meteostanica;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class TvrdjavaFragment extends Fragment {


    public TvrdjavaFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tvrdjava, container, false);
    }

}
```

What is the problem ? I just want the Tvrdjava text fragment to show when I select Tvrdjava from the Navigation Drawer.

Comment: *What is the problem ?* layout

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to use this:

```
TvrdjavaFragment tvrdjavaFragment = new TvrdjavaFragment();
        FragmentTransaction tvrdjavaFragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        tvrdjavaFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, tvrdjavaFragment);
        tvrdjavaFragmentTransaction.commit();
```